What is the proper way to setup Open vSwitch with NetworkManager Vlan , Bond and Bridge. with LACP in Alma8?
I set setup the network of my server in network-script with Vlan , Bond and Bridge. with LACP
I'm not sure how proper way to change this config to Open vSwitch setup, OS is Alma 8.10
Thank you.
cat ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE=bond0
TYPE=Bond
NAME=bond0
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100"
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none

cat ifcfg-bond0.1xxx
DEVICE=bond0.1xxx
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.x.x
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.x.x
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=1.1.1.1
VLAN=yes

cat ifcfg-ens2f1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=ens2f1
DEVICE=ens2f1
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes

cat ifcfg-ens3f0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=ens3f0
DEVICE=ens3f0
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes

cat ifcfg-bond0.12xx
DEVICE=bond0.12xx
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
BRIDGE=br0


cat ifcfg-br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=bridge0
DEVICE=br0
ONBOOT=yes

